# What is the difference between two real numbers?

Tags: definition, real-numbers

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers.  What does *the difference between x and y* mean?

1. $|x-y|$ or $|y-x|$?
2. $x-y$?
3. $y-x$?

To me, only the first case makes any sense whatsoever.  However, I cannot find a formal definition.

Comment: I think it means $x-y$, because $x$ is mentioned before $y$ in the sentence "difference between $x$ and $y$". However I agree that it's a little vague.

Comment: $|x-y|=|y-x|$ is the *distance* between two (real) numbers.

Comment: I would clearly vote for possibility $2$ , "$x-y$"

Comment: Anyone's guess, without further context.  If you had asked what is the "distance between two number on the real line, it would be $|x_1-x_2|$. if you asked about the "distance between two numbers, x and y, in $\mathbb R^2$, you'd need to use $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$.  So your question needs more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between $x$ and $y$ means either $(x-y)$ or $(y-x)$. If nothing is mentioned any one the two can be considered.

Though in general, in most cases, absolute value should be taken, i.e., $|x-y|$ or $|y-x|$.

Comment: You haven't considered that x, y might be anywhere in the plane, or anywhere in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

This question has come up a couple of times at the [Ask Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/) forum, e.g., [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222102338/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63137.html) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221031654/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69177.html).  The "official" answer is that the difference between two numbers is generally understood to be non-negative.  For a nice example, see this ["find the difference"](https://nrich.maths.org/6227) NRICH problem.

There are, of course, settings where "difference" refers to straight subtraction, so that a difference can be negative.  Usually it's clear whether "difference between $x$ and $y$" means $|x-y|$ or $x-y$, but occasionally it isn't.  (You might, for example, see if you can solve the NRICH problem by interpreting "difference" as "subtract the number on the right from the number on the left.")

Comment: Your conclusion assumes we're on the real line.  Fair enough.  As you mention, which I posted in a comment, *it depends on context not provided by the asker*.